# looking to sync icloud / drop box at a specific time ( to take advantage of lower cost internet between midnight and 6am)

Tags: macos, mac, dropbox, icloud

i'm being killed with upload volumes and have identified it's probably my drop box files, photos, etc being synced. I've had a look at IFTTT and can't find a way via a recipe.  Any ideas?  (Other than getting a package with unlimited broadband :-) )

Thanks
Katie